# How can I see the memory usage for each process or job?

Tags: linux, bash, memory

With SLURM and By this code I run a file on the cluster and at the end of the running, in an output file, it gives me the processing time, (Real, use, sys).
I need also to know how much memory every process use. Do you know with which code and where should I add it? I need to have the memory usage of the current Job in SLURM output, which I defined by BATCH at line 8.

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --mem=100G
#SBATCH --time=12:00:00
#SBATCH --error=slurm.%A_%a.err
#SBATCH --output=slurm.%A_%a.out   # %A becomes the job ID, %a becomes the array index

#SBATCH --mail-type=END,FAIL
#SBATCH --mail-user=m@uni.de
module purge
module load hpc
if [ "$mdepth" == "" ]
then
mdepth=3
fi
echo "config:"$SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID","$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID","$file","$solver
{ time ./ista --max-depth $mdepth --i $file | tee SomeFile.txt; } 2>&1
sacct --format=jobid,MaxRSS,MaxVMSize,start,end,CPUTimeRAW,NodeList
```

I can add this line at the end of the file but give me the memory usage of the previous Job's not the current job which is now finished.

```
sacct --format=jobid,MaxRSS,MaxVMSize,start,end,CPUTimeRAW,NodeList
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
program="./ista --max-depth $mdepth --i $file"

/usr/bin/time "--format" "\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S,\t%K avg tot KB,\t%M max resident KB" ${program}
```

or the more comprehensive

```
/usr/bin/time "--verbose" ${program}
```

However, don't you want to have "**time**" outside the braces, to get a complete picture of the task, not just the "**ista**" execution ?

Comment: by the "time" I can see the time which every job had during the processing in output which I defined  by "  #SBATCH --output=slurm.%A_%a.out"      I want to have, like time, the "memory usage" in the output as well. I used sacct --format=jobid,MaxRSS,MaxVMSize,start,end,CPUTimeRAW,NodeList at the last line of code but give me "the previous job's memory usage" not currently job.

Comment: Given what you have seen ... using what I offered above (where you originally used the "time" command) is what you need to use.  By the way, I gave the full path to time because when I did not use the full path, it refused to recognize the "--format" option.